# Can't load java, Failed setting boot class path after setting Environment variables

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova, quasar

I am trying to setup Cordova for running cordova-android9.0. My problem is that when I downgraded my java version, it no longer works.

I downloaded [Java 8](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java8-windows) and set my environment variables to:
**User variable Path** to:
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\bin`
and Gradle to this version:
`C:\Gradle\gradle-4.10.3\bin` (recommended by Cordova)

**System variables:**

```
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351
```

and Path the same as on user variables

When I run `java -version` in terminal it gives me error message:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Failed setting boot class path.
```

I cannot figure out why Java is not responding correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what could be breaking, but you can try clean installing java from your system once.
Uninstall all java versions -> reboot pc -> re-install correct JDK 8 from here:
https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html
and afterwards try to set the JAVA_HOME if not set properly.

Comment: that worked. I also now used another version jdk1.8.0_202 instead of jdk1.8.0_351. Could have been that as well!

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is the correct path of your jdk-

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\bin
```

Sometimes Its
`C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\bin`